# How to delete a specific array in an array of array references?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, arrayofarrays

I am interested in deleting a specific array from an array of array references. Towards this end I loop through the array references and look for a match. If a match is found, I attempt to delete this specific array reference by setting it to equal nothing. There are two strange things that happen in the script that I have written: 
1) The code seems to identify the presence of a match between the array of interest and an array reference, even before the array reference that matches it is processed. 
2) In trying to delete one specific array reference, I end up deleting all of them. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array_1 = ('CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT', 'CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT', 'CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT', 'GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT', 'CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT', 'CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT', 'CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT', 'CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT', 'CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT');
my @array_2 = ('CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT', 'TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT', 'CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA', 'CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT', 'CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT', 'CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT', 'GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT');
my @array_3 = ('TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT', 'TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT', 'TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT', 'TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT', 'TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT', 'TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT', 'TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT', 'TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT', 'TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT', 'TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT');
my @array_4 = ('TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT', 'TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT', 'TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT', 'TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT', 'TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT', 'TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT', 'TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT', 'TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT', 'TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT', 'TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT', 'CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT');

my $array_1_ref = \@array_1;
my $array_2_ref = \@array_2;
my $array_3_ref = \@array_3;
my $array_4_ref = \@array_4;

my @array_to_delete = ('CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT', 'TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT', 'CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA', 'CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT', 'CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT', 'CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT', 'GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT', 'CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT');
print "Array to delete: ", join(", ", @array_to_delete), "\n";

my @array_of_array_references = ($array_1_ref, $array_2_ref, $array_3_ref, $array_4_ref);

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array_of_array_references; $i++){
    print "\n", "A single array in the array of array references: ", join(", ", @{$array_of_array_references[$i]}), "\n";
    if (@array_to_delete = @{$array_of_array_references[$i]}){
            print "Both arrays match!\n";
            @{$array_of_array_references[$i]} = ();
    }
}
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array_of_array_references; $i++){
    print "\n", "A single array in the array of array references after removing one: ", join(", ", @{$array_of_array_references[$i]}), "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
Array to delete: CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT

A single array in the array of array references: CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT
Both arrays match!

A single array in the array of array references: CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT
Both arrays match!

A single array in the array of array references: TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT, TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT, TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT, TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT, TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT, TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT, TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT
Both arrays match!

A single array in the array of array references: TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT, TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT, TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT, TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT, TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT, TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT, TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT, TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT, CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT
Both arrays match!

A single array in the array of array references after removing one: 

A single array in the array of array references after removing one: 

A single array in the array of array references after removing one: 

A single array in the array of array references after removing one:
```

Expected output:

```
Array to delete: CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT

A single array in the array of array references: CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT

A single array in the array of array references: CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT
Both arrays match!

A single array in the array of array references: TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT, TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT, TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT, TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT, TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT, TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT, TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT

A single array in the array of array references: TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT, TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT, TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT, TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT, TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT, TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT, TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT, TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT, CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT

A single array in the array of array references after removing one: CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGAAATTT, GTCTTGCCTCATTGATAAAT, CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT, CTCTTCCCTCAATGATTTAA, CACTTGCCTCAATGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTCTTGCCTCAATGTTATAT, CTGATGCCTCATTGATATAT, CTGTTGGCTCAATCATATAT

A single array in the array of array references after removing one: TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT, TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT, TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT, TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT, TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT, TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT, TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT, CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT

A single array in the array of array references after removing one: TTTCTTTGCCCAATATATGT, TTTCTTTGCCGAATATAAGT, TTTCTATGCGCAATTTAAGT, TATCTTAGCCCAATTTTTGT, TTTCTTTGGCCTATTTTTGT, TTTGTTTGGCCATTTTATGT, TTTCTTTGGCGAATTTATCT, TTTCATTGCCCAATTATTGT, TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT, TTTCTTTGCCCAAAATAAGT, CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT
```

Comment: When you say "delete" do you mean to remove that element altogether (so that in the end the array has one element less), or to replace it with an empty string or `undef` (as the question itself says)?  (2) How large is your array, typically?

Comment: `If` statements use `==` and `eq` and not single `=` :)

Comment: Hi Zdim. I wish to remove the element altogether. My arrays vary in size, but can be on average between hundred and thousands of elements in size. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Hi Gerhard. Thanks for the information. I will update my code and question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code such as

```
if (@array_1 == @array_2)   # same number of elements?
```

tests whether the arrays have the same number of elements.  This is because the `==` operator imposes the [scalar context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) on both sides, and in scalar context an array is evaluated to return the number of its elements.

To test whether arrays are equal you need to compare their elements, with a few additional checks and refinements. As for many things in Perl, there are also modules that do that for us.

With [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Compare) for example, in its simplest usage:

```
use Array::Compare;

my $comp = Array::Compare->new;    
...
if ($comp->compare(\@ary1, \@ary2))  # they are equal
```

There is more that can be set up with the module, and there is a number of other modules for all kind of work with arrays and lists.

The code in the question also uses `=` (assignment!) instead of comparison `==`.

With a few simplifications

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);  # to show complex data structures

use Array::Compare;

my $cobj = Array::Compare->new;

my @data = ( 
   ['CTCTTGCCTCAATCATATAT', 'CTCTTGCCTCATTGATATAT', ... ],
   ['CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT', 'TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT', ... ],
   ...
);

my @ary_to_del = ('CACTTGCCTCAATGTAATAT', 'TATCATTGCCCAATTTAAGT', ...);

foreach my $ra (@data) {
    @$ra = () if $cobj->compare(\@ary_to_del, $ra);
}

dd \@data;
```

This "empties" the anonymous arrays in `@data` that are equal to `@ary_to_del`, as code in the question does, but their array references remain in `@data` even as there is nothing in them.

If you were rather to remove such elements altogether then overwrite the array

```
@data = grep { not $cobj->compare(\@ary_to_del, $_) } @data;
```

instead of the `foreach` loop above.  This uses [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to filter the input list, whereby only elements for which the code block evaluates true are returned in the output list, assigned to `@data`.

Comment: Hi zdim. Thank you for your response. I tried to use grep instead of the foreach loop. I came up against two issues: 1) @ary_to_del needed to be dereferenced and 2) it only kept the array I wanted to delete. How do I use this to eliminate only the array I wish to delete? The foreach loop did exactly as you said it would.

Comment: @Emma  right -- (2) only those which _aren't_ equal should pass so the condition need be negated.  (1) the method `compare` needs an array _reference_, as in the first use.  Fixed.  Sorry about that